# Error: An error occurred while preparing the command definition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures, complextype

I have 2 stored procedures under **Function Imports** in Model Browser, lets say ***ProcA*** and ***ProcB***, each with their own Complex Type, let's say ***TypeA*** and ***Type2***, respectively.

**TypeA properties:**

```
Int32 SomeId;
String PersonName;
String PersonAddress;
```

**TypeB properties**

```
Int32 SomeId;
String PersonName;
String PersonAddress;
Int32 Age;
Int32 Height;
```

Everything is good, fully functional with no exception except when I try to nest ***TypeA*** into ***TypeB*** as ***TypeB*** is basically a replica of ***TypeA*** plus it has 2 of its own additional properties.

**TypeB properties**

```
Int32 Age;
Int32 Height;
TypeA TypeAObj; // nesting typeA here
```

ProcA works fine but when I call ProcB it throws an exception:

> Error: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See
>   the inner exception for details.
>
> Message = "Nested ComplexType property 'TypeA' in the ReturnType
>   'TypeB' of the function 'ProcB' is not supported, please consider
>   flattening the nested ComplexType property."

Do i have to use flattened complex types and nesting is not possible in my case?

I'm just trying to reduce the lines of code and force reusability.

Any input on this would be great.
Please let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

PS: Error occurs in DB.Context.cs file

```
return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<TypeB>("ProcB", param1, param2);
```

### Thanks

Comment: Impossible to tell without looking into ProcB.We can help you if you provide the code.

Comment: @Juan I updated the question with some more information. If I call both procedures with their system generated complex types i.e. before I next one into another, it works fine. So stored procedures are fine and return values fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to work. As of EF 6.0, it's not supported.

Check out this link. The property pulls out the localized string for the problem behind this error and it still exists in EF 6.0:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.data.entity.design.resources.mappingdetails_errcomplextypepropertiesnotsupported(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Resources.MappingDetails_ErrComplexTypePropertiesNotSupported

The version history does not indicate they have addressed this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574253(v=vs.113).aspx

I found a thread going back to 2010 that says "it's in the backlog":

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c412a7d7-9455-47bc-87dd-46d3f0809b1b/mapping-a-stored-procedure-to-an-entity-that-contains-complex-types?forum=adodotnetentityframework

And a quick local test with VS2013 and the latest EF confirms this:

[image: Quick local test in VS2013 with latest EF confirms this.]